# How to dynamically create a div inside a pre-given div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The markup I have:

```
   <div id="list"></div>
```

There is a big object. What I wanna do is creating divs according to objects fields  but not hardcoding them. So I do it this way:

```
for (var key in table) {
    console.log(key);
    if (table.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var div_card[key] = document.createElement('div');
        div_card[key].addClass('card');
        $('.card').innerHTML = table[key].name;
        div_card[key].appendTo('#list');
    }
}
```

There is a pre-given div of id list, I wanna apend a new div of class card into it and there are multiole divs of these class. When adding class I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
    at js.js:2604
(anonymous) @ js.js:2604
```

I added key as an index because this is gonna be a collection of divs (an array). What's wrong with the code?

P.S.
Finally I wanna obtain this structure

```
#list
  .card*100
```

Comment: What you have inside `div_card`? Also what how did you define the `table` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit the table is there https://jsfiddle.net/f2n5ejsk/ I put there a value of table[key].name but with no success

Comment: Please share the structure for `table` and div_card variables

Comment: Your table I see is an array.. then why `for.. in..`?

Comment: @STEEL structure is above. For the divs I only do .iinerHTML method and have some css stzles

Comment: @STEEL Is not an array, is an object. I wanna make operations with its different fields...

Comment: I'm at mobile. Just wondering why didn't you use React

Comment: @Bereznyak I see table is an array of objects..

Comment: @STEEL cause I'm not a friend with it so far ;)

Comment: @ArupRakshit anyway the problem is not with the for but with the addClass method

Comment: `table` is an array, so you probably need to first loop through the array and then `for.. in..` each object within the array. Also js doesn't understand `div_card[key]` cause you haven't defined `div_card` yet. You have an odd mix of jquery and javascript here, may be more readable if you use more of the corresponding jquery functions or just go with vanilla javascript.

Comment: @benvc         var div_card[key] = document.createElement('div');
Is it not a definition of div_card?

Comment: No it is not. `div_card[key]` attempts to access / assign a property to `div_card` but you have not defined `div_card` as anything yet. You could do something like `var div_card = {};` and then assign properties to it subsequently. That said, the answer from @ArupRakshit does a nice job of removing the unnecessary code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, you want to create `<div>` from objects of `table` list. I'd do it using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-object) as below.

```js
var table = [{
    "atomicNumber": 1,
    "symbol": "H",
    "name": "Hydrogen",
    "atomicMass": "1.00794(4)",
    "cpkHexColor": "FFFFFF",
    "electronicConfiguration": "1s1",
    "electronegativity": 2.2,
    "atomicRadius": 37,
    "ionRadius": "",
    "vanDelWaalsRadius": 120,
    "ionizationEnergy": 1312,
    "electronAffinity": -73,
    "oxidationStates": "-1, 1",
    "standardState": "gas",
    "bondingType": "diatomic",
    "meltingPoint": 14,
    "boilingPoint": 20,
    "density": 0.0000899,
    "groupBlock": "nonmetal",
    "yearDiscovered": 1766
  },
  {
    "atomicNumber": 2,
    "symbol": "He",
    "name": "Helium",
    "atomicMass": "4.002602(2)",
    "cpkHexColor": "D9FFFF",
    "electronicConfiguration": "1s2",
    "electronegativity": "",
    "atomicRadius": 32,
    "ionRadius": "",
    "vanDelWaalsRadius": 140,
    "ionizationEnergy": 2372,
    "electronAffinity": 0,
    "oxidationStates": "",
    "standardState": "gas",
    "bondingType": "atomic",
    "meltingPoint": "",
    "boilingPoint": 4,
    "density": 0.0001785,
    "groupBlock": "noble gas",
    "yearDiscovered": 1868
  }
]

var $list = $('#list');

table.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('<div>', {
    class: 'card',
    text: obj.name
  }).appendTo($list);
})
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f2n5ejsk/2/
Any idea how can I do so that I get a structure of
#list
  .card
    .front
    .back

cause as for now I get such a thing http://prntscr.com/kocval

Comment: You are still using that old wrong code? Also I don't get your question..

Comment: for the one card div I need two front and back divs inside

Comment: as You see at printscreen there are too much of those